# c++ templates with template type deduction error

Tags: c++

## include

```
    template <typename R, typename S, typename T>
    T const min (R const& a, S const& b)
    {
        T val;

        if( a > b )
        {
            val = static_cast<T>( b );
        }
        else
        {
            val = static_cast<T>( a );
        }
        return  val;
    }

    // CANNOT change anything above this line  --------------------

    void B()
    {
       int val =0;

       // Only change the next line

        val = min (5,4.2);

        assert( val == 4 );
   }
```

---

when the code is compiled the following error is thrown

error C2783: 'const T min(const R &,const S &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'

Stuck trying to solve this.. . any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you guess why T is not being deduced?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is telling you that it can't figure out what type `T` is supposed to be in your call to `min`, since you haven't specified it and the return type of a function or function template are not used during overload resolution or template argument deduction (unless it's a conversion operator, of course).

Since you can't change the definition of `min` (which is stupid) your only choice is to explicitly specify `T` in the call. However, since `T` is the last template parameter, you have to specify the two preceding template arguments too! Like this:

```
val = min<int, double, int>(5, 4.2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler cannot deduce the template argument if you don't ***use it***.

That being said what you would do in this situation is specify in specify the template arguments when you call the function `min`. Just like this:

```
void B()
{
    int val = 0;

   // Only change the next line

    val = min<int, double, int>(5, 4.2);

    assert(val == 4);
}
```

Comment: You are most welcome, please, accept an answer to help SO community!